# Is there a negative connotation to Yair Mazolam - יאיר מזלם?

Tags: words, chabad

Yesterday [The Yeshiva World](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ll.jpg) posted a letter the Lubavitcher Rabbi Zatzal sent to Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu upon the birth of his son Yair. In the letter the Rabbi handwrote the words V'Yair Mazolam - ויאיר מזלם. The [article](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/212417/lubavitcher-rebbe-ztls-letter-to-yair-netanyahu.html) went on to say about the term V'Yair Mazolam as quoted:

> Chabadniks explain [it] is generally not a term used by the Rebbe as a good
>   omen.

Where did the Rabbi use this term with a negative connotation? The only place I find the Rabbi used this term was in [Sichos Kodesh 5741:3 page 129](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4628&st=&pgnum=153&hilite=) and it is definitely not negative there.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to eat my hat, but "Chabadniks explain," without a name or source, sounds like "some random Chabadnik I asked who wanted to find some portent of this story in the Rebbe's letter said..." "V'Yair Mazolam" is (as you've discovered) not a blessing the Rebbe gave commonly, but the obvious explanation is that it has a lot more to do with the boy's name. Then again, it's also not that common to see handwritten comments on the childrens' names in the Rebbe's congratulatory letters (I think), but even so, I doubt I'll have to start chewing any time soon.

Comment: @HodofHod: The article did not say it was uncommon, it said it was not a good omen. Why is V'yair Mazolam not a good omen?

Comment: I allowed for the possibility that there was some miscommunication between the author and the source, perhaps turning an indefinite article into a definite one, and that the bad omen was that the Rebbe found it necessary to give _a_ special blessing. If you find out either of these are true, let me know so I can finally discover what felt tastes like. ;) That being said, perhaps you should add the  question of "did" to your current question of "where."

Answer (score 2):

The way in which the above-quoted phrase is written, "[it] is generally not a term used by the Rebbe as a good omen," could mean merely that it was unusual for the Rebbe to write such a phrase - for any reason. On those rare occasions where he did use such a phrase, however, it can indicate a positive blessing (that their mazal should brighten, i.e. be good).

It seems like the Rebbe just used this as a cute way of wishing the baby a more personal blessing, since the baby's name was Yair.